# Using cin.get(); Twice

Tags: c++

I don't understand why it might be needed twice, this is a quote from the book I am reading;

> The cin.get() statement reads the next keystroke, so this statement causes the program to wait until you press the Enter key. (No keystrokes get sent to a program until you
>   press Enter, so there’s no point in pressing another key.) The second statement is needed if
>   the program otherwise leaves an unprocessed keystroke after its regular input. For example, if you enter a number, you type the number and then press Enter.The program reads
>   the number but leaves the Enter keystroke unprocessed, and it is then read by the first
>   cin.get().

I place it in the source code and don't see the point of it being there twice.

You type in some numbers and press enter it ends the program, only different is you press enter twice if nothing is entered before ending.

The point of it is to pause the program, and it does that so why the use of it twice?

Comment: "*cin.get() statement reads the next keystroke*" is, at best, only almost correct. What book are you quoting?

Comment: The answer is pretty much in the quote. Depending on what input you get, there might be a newline left in the buffer that's read by the first `cin.get()`. If there's a newline there, you need two. The only way I know of doing it generically is `cin.sync(); cin.get();`, but `cin.sync()` is not guaranteed to do what it does for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cin.get();` retrieves a single character from the input. So if you have `5\n` (`\n` being equivalent to pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) on the input, `cin.get();` will return `5`, and another `cin.get();` will return `\n`. If you are reading multiple numbers one after another, say in a `while` loop, if you forget about the `\n` character, you are likely going to run into issues.

Using `cin.ignore(256, '\n');` can also correct this issue once you are done reading the characters you want or care about.

Comment: Thanks, "you forget about the \n character, you are likely going to run into issues." - how will forgetting it occur?, because the user has to press ENTER to input.

Comment: If you forget to handle the character, you may read it in as "valid" input.

Comment: Also, just from a personal standpoint: `int a; cin >> a;`. I prefer to avoid using `get` and `getline` and other misc. functions. In my experience, it's less readable, and less safe.